# GETDATE() and Multiple Servers connecting via a listener

Tags: ssis, listener, getdate

We have 3 servers London, Amsterdam, Frankfurt. Connect via a listener. so using GetDate() to populate tables etc will give a different result depending on if connection to London or not. What is the easiest way to always get the London time.

Thanks
Geoff

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Easiest to use GETUTCDATE() instead.  The *datetimeoffset* returned is unambiguous.
To get a UK time, convert using AT TIME ZONE, then convert to *datetime* or *datetime2*:

```
SELECT CONVERT(datetime2(0),CONVERT(datetimeoffset,GETUTCDATE()) AT TIME ZONE 'GMT 
Standard Time')
```

**Note** that timezone 'Greenwich Standard Time' returns GMT, which is not UK time in summer.  Timezone 'GMT Standard Time' reflects UK time in both summer and winter - which is *not* GMT, but GMT+1 in summer.  This doesn't seem
to be documented, and the names are not helpful!